# Join Two Data frames- Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have  two Excel files which I loaded into dataframes:

1. In first Frame I have States `State1,2,3...` as column names:
2. In second Frame I have `State1,2,3...` as column values

[image: Check Data Formats Here]

I need to merge these two dataframes, based on value of `state`.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You should add some reproducible code to the question so we can see what you have already tried?

Comment: your question is not clare...

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Please see existing duplicates on `[pandas] wide to long` and `merge`

Comment: what would the merged dataframe look like?

Comment: add desired output so as to avoid confusion